# Sequentially calculate changes in R data frame value based on categorical variables

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have constructed a set of indicators for weather prediction and I would like to backtest my algorithm by using different sets of them in R. Although I had some experience with merging using data table I cannot figure out a way to do this particular task. Here's a portion of my data

```
Time TempC Index1 Index2 Index3 Index4
1    25.0  Up     Down   Down   Down
2    25.2  Up     Up     Up     Down
3    25.6  Up     Up     Up     Up
4    25.0  Down   Down   Down   Up
5    24.7  Down   Down   Down   Down
6    23.6  Down   Down   Down   Down
7    28.9  Up     Up     Up     Down
8    30.0  Up     Up     Up     Up
```

Ideally I would pick a set of indicators let's say Index1 and Index2 and calculate the differences based on the first and last instance of Up and Down signals. For example when taking Index1 as the only predictor;

```
Time TempC       TempDiff 
1,3  25.0, 25.6  0.6
4,6  25.0, 23.6  1.4
7,8  28.9, 30.0  1.1
```

And when taking both Index1 and Index2;

```
Time TempC       TempDiff 
2,3  25.2, 25.6  0.4
4,6  25.0, 23.6  1.4
7,8  28.9, 30.0  1.1
```

What matters to me the most is the difference. Concatenating start and end temperature and time scales with commas is completely optional. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**edit**

I would be interested to also know if there's any way to ignore intermediate sets of values that do not meet the criteria in the case of two or more indices like the following;

```
Time TempC Index1 Index2 Index3 Index4
1    25.0  Up     Down   Down   Down
2    25.2  Up     Up     Up     Down
3    25.6  Up     Up     Up     Up
4    25.0  Down   Down   Down   Up
5    24.7  Down   Down   Down   Down
6    23.6  Down   Down   Down   Down
7    28.9  Up     Up     Up     Down
8    29.3  Up     Down   Down   Down
9    30.0  Up     Up     Up     Up
```

The desired result above when using both Index1 and Index2 would be to ignore the 8th line and normally calculate the difference with lines 7 and 9.

Finally, it would be useful to add another column indicating the direction (Up or Down) which will let me quantify the reliability of the model like this

```
Time TempC       TempDiff  Direction
2,3  25.2, 25.6  0.4       Up
4,6  25.0, 23.6  -1.4      Down
7,8  28.9, 30.0  1.1       Up
```

Comment: *"For example when taking Index1 as the only predictor;"* What are you predicting/modelling? I don't see any statistical model; nor do I understand what you are trying to do. Could you please clarify?

Comment: I'm trying to predict the movement of the temperature. I have generated different indicators using neural networks for different time intervals and would like to test their reliability.

Answer (score 3):

A solution using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) and [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table).

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  # Create Run Length ID
  mutate(ID = rleid(Index1)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  # Filter groups with n > 1
  filter(n() > 1) %>%
  # Summarise the data by first and last value of each group
  summarise(Time = paste(first(Time), last(Time), sep = ", "),
            TempRange = paste(first(TempC), last(TempC), sep = ", "),
            TempDiff = abs(first(TempC) - last(TempC))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-ID)

dat2
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Time  TempRange TempDiff
#  <chr> <chr>        <dbl>
# 1 1, 3  25, 25.6     0.600
# 2 4, 6  25, 23.6     1.40 
# 3 7, 8  28.9, 30     1.10
```

If you want to consider more than one columns, you can provide multiple columns to the `rleid` function.

```
dat3 <- dat %>%
  # Create Run Length ID
  mutate(ID = rleid(Index1, Index2)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  # Filter groups with n > 1
  filter(n() > 1) %>%
  # Summarise the data by first and last value of each group
  summarise(Time = paste(first(Time), last(Time), sep = ", "),
            TempRange = paste(first(TempC), last(TempC), sep = ", "),
            TempDiff = abs(first(TempC) - last(TempC))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-ID)

dat3

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   Time  TempRange  TempDiff
#   <chr> <chr>         <dbl>
# 1 2, 3  25.2, 25.6    0.400
# 2 4, 6  25, 23.6      1.40 
# 3 7, 8  28.9, 30      1.10
```

Comment: Thank you, excellent response! Before marking it as solved I have two more questions; a) is it possible to ignore intermediate rows that do not have the same values when using more than one index, b) it would be useful to add another column that indicates the quality of the signal (Up or Down) to facilitate quantitative analysis. I have edited the original post to get an idea of what I'm asking.

Comment: @civy I don't know the answers of your two follow-up questions. It is not clear to me how to define the intermediate step or the quality of the signal in some cases.